# Why is it that the box loop diagrams do not contribute to the $\phi\phi\rightarrow \phi\phi$ one-loop beta-function in a $\phi^3$ theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams

I have read at a few places that the [box diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Feynman_diagrams) do not contribute as they are [UV finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet_fixed_point), but why would a UV finite diagram not contribute to the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)? Or is it something else I am missing here?

Comment: $\uparrow$ in 6D?

Answer (score 1):

Just to fix ideas (since the exact way this works depends on the scheme you are using), let's work in the Wilsonian renormalization group. The beta function describes the dependence of the bare parameters on the cutoff, in order that physical observables do not depend on the cutoff. If a given diagram does not depend on the cutoff (finite = cutoff independent), then that means that this diagram cannot contribute to the cutoff dependence of a coupling constant.

Comment: And this generalizes to any theory, such that, as long as the considered loop diagram is UV finite, it will never contribute to the beta function? Also, will the diagram also not contribute to the coupling constant correction?

Comment: @Fizzicist First question: Yes, for example [$N=4$ super-Yang Mills theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N_%3D_4_supersymmetric_Yang%E2%80%93Mills_theory) is *conformal* because its parameters are protected from renormalization. It is a finite theory to all loop order.  Second question: The diagram can still contribute a finite part to the vertex correction, even if it doesn't contribute the beta function (which comes from the divergent contribution).